# How can you check if a graph is balanced or not using NetworkX?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I can only check if the sign of the neighbors of a node is positive or negative, but I don't know how to check the signs of a triad within the graph.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: How is balanced defined?

Comment: For every set of three nodes, all edges must be labeled + or only one of them must be labeled +, for the network to be balanced. If this is violated even just once, the entire network becomes unbalanced.